# Failed to resolve component - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Has anyone experienced this error:

vue.global.js:1571 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

I've already checked that here on StackOverFlow, someone has already gone through this, but I've done all the indicated implementations, and I'm still having this error.

Other components like this one in question are working.

Thanks

Update Vue.js and dependencies.
And also correction in vue.global.js file.
I hoped it worked. But it didn't work yet.

Comment: please provide minimal reproductime scenario. a link for a github project sampling the issue or codesandbox or stackblitz

Comment: Not sure what other solutions can be offered when you said you tried the solutions from other posts.  Without any knowledge of your app or component, we can only point to those other solutions for you to try.  If you included some code, someone could maybe point out what specifically is wrong with it...